# Selecting Categories from a joined table and concatenating to form listing results

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am a bit confused about using GROUP_CONCAT in MySQL.

To explain, I am working on a listings directory, sort of like Yelp for example.  A user filters different criteria and is returned with different places.

For example, if a user wants to see all places that have been categorized (or tagged) as "Restaurant", or maybe "Lounge" then they will see only those places, but also they should be presented with any other tagged categories.

To do this, I have built some tables in my database. The main tables that relate to this question are the tables `places` and `categories` and `place_category_rel` as such:

**places** table:

```
+----+------------------+
| id | name             | 
+----+------------------+
| 1  | Johns Restaurant |
+----+------------------+
| 2  | Jims Place       |
+----+------------------+
| 3  | Cafe Luna        |
+----+------------------+
```

**place_category_rel** table

```
+----------+-------------+
| place_id | category_id |
+----------+-------------+
| 1        | 1           |
+----------+-------------+
| 1        | 2           |
+----------+-------------+
```

**categories** table

```
+----+------------+
| id | name       |
+----+------------+
| 1  | Lounge     |
+----+------------+
| 2  | Restaurant |
+----+------------+
| 3  | Night Club |
+----+------------+
```

To obtain all places I use the following query:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
       group_concat(DISTINCT cat.name separator ',') as categories
FROM places p
LEFT JOIN places_categories_rel rel ON p.id=rel.place_id
LEFT JOIN categories cat ON cat.id=rel.category_id
GROUP BY p.id
```

Which gets me this result set:

```
+----+------------------+--------------------+
| id | name             | categories         |
+----+------------------+--------------------+
| 1  | Johns Restaurant | Lounge,Restaurant  |
+----+------------------+--------------------+
| 2  | Jims Place       | Null               |
+----+------------------+--------------------+
| 3  | Cafe Luna        | Null               |
+----+------------------+--------------------+
```

The above works great. However, when I add a WHERE clause to filter down on places that are categorized as "Lounge" , I lose the other category:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
       group_concat(DISTINCT cat.name separator ',') as categories
FROM places p
LEFT JOIN places_categories_rel rel ON p.id=rel.place_id
LEFT JOIN categories cat ON cat.id=rel.category_id
WHERE cat.name = 'Lounge' 
GROUP BY p.id
```

Result:

```
+----+------------------+------------+
| id | name             | categories |
+----+------------------+------------+
| 1  | Johns Restaurant | Lounge     |
+----+------------------+------------+
```

what I would like is this result set instead:

```
+----+------------------+--------------------+
| id | name             | categories         |
+----+------------------+--------------------+
| 1  | Johns Restaurant | Lounge, Restaurant |
+----+------------------+--------------------+
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly, you are trying to get all categories for a given place if they have a specific category.  Assuming so, one option is to use  `exists`:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
       group_concat(DISTINCT cat.name separator ',') as categories
FROM places p
   LEFT JOIN places_categories_rel rel ON p.id=rel.place_id
   LEFT JOIN categories cat ON cat.id=rel.category_id
WHERE EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM places_categories_rel pcr 
       JOIN categories c ON c.id=pcr.category_id
   WHERE name = 'Lounge'  AND p.id=pcr.place_id
)
GROUP BY p.id
```

---

Not sure you need `outer joins` in this case either -- probably would work the same with `inner joins`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please explain how the `WHERE EXISTS` section works? what does the line  `SELECT 1` actually do?

Comment: @CodeGodie -- `exists` is used how it sounds -- does a given record exist matching specific criteria.  And `select 1` is arbitrary -- this query is saying if a given place_id (based on the where criteria of the subquery) has a category with `Lounge`, then return true.  So for any matching places, all categories will be returned.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you for the explanation. So far I like your answer but I will wait for other answers to get different perspectives. Ill keep you posted.

Answer (score 1):

When using a `LEFT JOIN`, conditions on all but the first table should be in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
       group_concat(DISTINCT cat.name separator ',') as categories
FROM places p LEFT JOIN
     places_categories_rel rel
     ON p.id = rel.place_id LEFT JOIN
     categories cat
     ON cat.id = rel.category_id AND cat.name = 'Lounge' 
GROUP BY p.id;
```

Remember:  A `LEFT JOIN` returns all rows in the first table, regardless of whether the `ON` clause returns true, false, or `NULL`.  If the `ON` condition is not true, then all columns in the second (and subsequent) tables are `NULL`.

When you test for `cat.name = 'Lounge'` in the `WHERE` clause, `cat.name` is `NULL` for the rows that do not match -- hence they are filtered out.

EDIT:

If you only want the category of lounge in the results (with others), then just add a `having` clause:

```
SELECT p.id,
       p.name,
       group_concat(DISTINCT cat.name separator ',') as categories
FROM places p LEFT JOIN
     places_categories_rel rel
     ON p.id = rel.place_id LEFT JOIN
     categories cat
     ON cat.id = rel.category_id
GROUP BY p.id
HAVING SUM(cat.name = 'Lounge') > 0;
```

I think this is the simplest approach.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately its not the answer I was looking for. Perhaps I explained myself incorrectly. I want the query to say _"only show me the places that have the category of Lounge"_. The result should be only one row: Johns Restaurant, showing the category Lounge(what we asked for) but also "Restaurant" because its also a category of that place.. Does that make more sense?